# Is there a way to use spring filter chains without spring-security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, servlet-filters

I want to add a couple of filters to my spring web app, but there won't be anything about security in them, at least for now. So. All I'm able to do without spring-security is to define multiple filters in web.xml (old way of defining filters). It seems strange that to be able to use spring filter chains, I need to add spring-security as a dependency for my project. Maybe I'm doing something wrong and there are indeed filter chains that can be used without spring-security dependency?

Comment: I won't post this as an answer, as I'm not totally sure. However, Spring Security filters are not the classic Servlet filters. I'm pretty sure they are AOP pointcuts, which intercept requests to a method. Try ctrl-clicking one of your Spring Security annotations to see what you find. Digging into the Spring code can be fun. :)

Comment: Thanks, Steve.  I was sure that spring filter = spring security filter. But it seems that it's not true.

Answer (score 3):

Spring Security is able to bundle multiple filters into a single Filter using the [FilterChainProxy](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/FilterChainProxy.java) which is included within Spring Security. Since the code exists within Spring Security, you cannot use it without adding a dependency on spring-security-web short of copy pasting the code into your own project (which is acceptable by the license). The FilterChainProxy is indeed the Spring Bean defined Filter that the DelegatingFilterProxy delegates to. So it looks like this

```
DelegatingFilterProxy
  -> delegates to FilterChainProxy
     -> delegates to multiple Filter's defined on the FilterChainProxy
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DelegatingFilterProxy](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/DelegatingFilterProxy.html). This [Spring Forum Entry](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/11091-howto-the-joy-that-is-delegatingfilterproxy) has a good example of how to use it.

Comment: At first I used DelegatingFilterProxy and a simple filter in there. As I understood from the link you posted, the idea is to add parameters to filter and thus manage what filter does. meanwhile it solves the problem: allows multiple actions to be done in one real filter. But it's not as transparent as filter chaining, which is what's going on in spring security filters.